# Redux form validation on submit or on click not validating until after a user types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I think I may have something configured wrong or maybe am misunderstanding.

I have a form with two fields, that I want to be validated. The validation is to just make sure something has been entered in the field.

I could disable the submit button while the form is `pristine` but I don't really like doing that. I'd rather let the user click submit and then see what they are missing in the form or submit the form if its good to go.

But, the form only seems to validate if I type somthing. I can click both fields, click out, cause a blur and even submit the form and it wont throw any validations at me. It only validates if I type something and then erase it will it say its invalid.

My component...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Field} from "redux-form";
import {renderField, renderTextArea} from './controls';

class AddCommentModal extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalOpen: false
        };
        this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
    }

    toggleModal() {
        this.setState({
            modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen
        });
        this.props.reset();
    }


    render() {
        const {
            modalOpen
        } = this.state;
        const {
            submitting, handleSubmit, addMessage
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Open Modal</button>
                <div className={`modal ${modalOpen ? 'is-active' : ''}`}>
                    <div className="modal-background">{}</div>
                    <div className="modal-card">
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(addMessage.bind(this))}>
                            <header className="modal-card-head">
                                <p className="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
                                <button className="delete" aria-label="close" type="button" onClick={this.toggleModal}>close</button>
                            </header>
                            <section className="modal-card-body">

                                <Field name="name" type="text"
                                       component={renderField} label="Name"
                                />
                                <Field name="message" rows={6}
                                       component={renderTextArea} label="Message"
                                />
                                <div>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                            <footer className="modal-card-foot">
                                <button className="button is-success" type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Save changes</button>
                                <button className="button" type="button"  onClick={this.toggleModal}>Cancel</button>
                            </footer>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddCommentModal;
```

My container for the component

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import AddCommentModal from '../components/AddCommentModal';
import {reduxForm} from "redux-form";
import {addComment} from '../actions/commentActions';
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
        addMessage: dispatchAddMessage.bind(this)
    };
};
const validate = values => {
    let errors = {};
    if(!values.name || values.name.trim() === '') errors.name = 'Please Provide Your Name';
    if(!values.message || values.message.trim() === '') errors.message = 'Please Provide A Message';
    return errors;
};

const dispatchAddMessage = (values, dispatch, ctx) => {
    return dispatch(addComment(values.name, values.message));
};

const AddCommentModalForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'AddCommentModalForm',
    validate,
})(AddCommentModal);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddCommentModalForm);
```

I initally had Field Level validations because the validations are so simple, but that didn't work so tried sync validations but that still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to read more information about the validation of HTML forms. If you use the tools that you have correctly you will have the desired result

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying? Wraily? And the problem isn't misunderstanding validations, the form validates correctly, just not when I want it to. If I re-write it in the same format as in the redux-form example, it works the way I'm expecting. But using the container/component form I have it only works after a keystroke.
Edit: Updating to reply to your updated comment. Could you be more helpful as to what I'm using wrong?

Comment: you can use require for unfill inputs or pathron for comlex text validations as emails or phones, or even only numbers inputs

Comment: @ErnestoAlfonso the problem isn't the validation is failing. The fields validate properly just not when they are supposed to. The form just doesn't show the validation until after typing. I can see the fields are invalid and touched in my redux state.

Comment: sorry if i'm slow on this, you need the validation when input make a blur?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this issue, but there appears to be an issue related to validation and the use of the `reset()` method. Refer to the open issue on GitHub here:

https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/2971

There are some workarounds and more details contained within the thread. Since you're using the `reset` method in your code it might be applicable to your problem.